# default user for sudo command

Tags: linux, sudo

In my `sudo` command, if I don't mention `username`, will it take `root` as the default user? For example, In the following command-

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/computerLinux/
```

using which target user will it execute the command?

Comment: sudo means "root user". So, it will obviously take the credentials of the "root" account.

Comment: @palerdot: Yet the headline of the `man` page reads: "sudo - execute a command *as another user*" :-)

Comment: but what if a root user does not exist, has no passwd set and no ~ dir?

Comment: is there a way to print out and configure the default user?

Comment: root does not need a psswd since `sudo` grants all permissions to the requesting sudoer. The ~ dir of root is `/root` **not** `/home/root` Thus you are able to edit / delete files inside `/root` with `sudo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, from manual of `sudo`:

> -u  The -u (user) option causes sudo to run the specified command as a user **other than root**. To specify a uid instead of a username, use #uid.